# Formatting TimeZoneDesignator

Tags: java, datetime, aem, simpledateformat

Need to format this String `2017-08-01T15:43:45+0530` to `2017-08-01T15:43:45+05:30` using a particular date format. Tried with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ`. Did not work..

```
Date modified = aemPage.getProperties().get(cq:lastModified, Date.class);
private DateFormat seoDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ");

String formattedDate = seoDateFormat.format(modified));
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three `X` to get off set like

```
Sign TwoDigitHours : Minutes
```

I suggest to use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) if you are working with java8 or higher:

```
String input = "2017-08-01T15:43:45+0530";

DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, parser);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");

System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(formatter)); // 2017-08-01T15:43:45+05:30
```

Since `2017-08-01T15:43:45+05:30` is [`ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), you can also just use:

```
String outPut = offsetDateTime.toString();
```

Update:

If you want to use `SimpleDateFormat`, try:

```
String input = "2017-08-01T15:43:45+0530";

SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

Date date = parser.parse(input);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");

System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

But this only works when your system's offset is `0530` since `Date` does not hold time zone information.

Comment: The above code works but can this be done using DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat like this -                                                                                                          
 DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

Comment: Yeah, but `SimpleDateFormat` is outdated and troublesome, you can use `java.time` package.

Comment: without OffsetDateTime

Comment: I am asked to use SDF itself !